# How to create pdf file using Zend Framework 1.2

Tags: zend-framework

How to create pdf file using Zend Framework 1.2. This .pdf file will contain data from table.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [htmltoPDF](http://html2pdf.fr/en/default) and it worked fine.

Comment: Will it work for zend framework. Can you elaborate whole procedure.